# ANTLR parsing : how to ignore certain text

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I am a newbie to antlr and i have written a basic **combined grammar** to parse my jsp file. I am using antlrworks 1.4.3... Here, I need my grammar to ignore certain lines of text, instead of showing 
 **Mismatched exception error**.

What should I do? should i write a separate rule to ignore few lines of unwanted code.

For example, there is something like:

```
              <myTag: selectName = "SelectedLocation" html = "onChange=onChangeType('LOCATION', 'PLACE')"; util.myProject.display();"/>
```

How should i write a rule to ignore such junk lines in between code.. can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple lexer to ignore the sea around the islands (tags). Then parse the tags with ANTLR.  Or use ANTLR 4 and see book for XML parsing.